# Favicon in community

Tags: community, customer-portal, favicon

I have a crated a 100% custom branded community and the only missing element is the favicon. I set the Favorite Icon in the force.com setting of the community and also tried `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.Favicon)}" type="image/x-icon" />` but neither load the icon that I am wanting.

How can I replace the cloud?

Comment: I found that the `<link rel="shortcut icon" ...` only worked across all browsers when put in the `<head>...</head>` part of the page.

Comment: I did create a `<head></head>` inside of the `<apex:page>`. Does the file type matter? I am using a .ICO which is what I use on our corporate site, not sure what is wrong honestly. Looking at the code on the rendered page the `<link />` is not between the `<head>` tags. How can I force items between the `<head>`?

Comment: .ico works fine for me. (I don't have the `type` parameter set.) In my pages I have the head section explicitly defined and all the standard Salesforce output turned off using `showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false"`. That gives me just the head section I want.

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the similar issue related to Favicon in my Community(Napili template) and I have fixed it. Credit goes to @glls. Here is the link to my question: [Favicon is not working outside of the Community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174181/favicon-is-not-working-outside-of-the-community)